finding a linear transformation
I have got a task, where I have to change the basis of a linear transformation „A“ from the standard basis into a basis „B = (b_1,b_2,b_3)“. But the thing is, in the first place, I have to find A.
There is this condition given:
A * b_1 = -b_1
A * b_2 = b_2
A * b_3 = b_3
I don‘t know how this makes sense, that the matrix negates one vector, and leaves others unchanged.
Basically, how should I find this transformation A?
Thank you in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You want to know what the matrix is with $A(x,y,z)^T = (-x,y,z)^T$. Set up this system of equations and solve it. Note that $(x,y,z)^T$ is just $xb_1+yb_2+zb_3$.
